# El Documento base no existe o no es un directorio legible

Tags: java, mvc, spring-boot, tomcat, error404

Hola estoy viendo un tutorial y al momento de ejecutar el servidor me marca el siguiente error:

> El Documento base
>   C:\work\SpringMVCSignupLoginPasswordEncoder\target\SpringMVCSignupLoginPasswordEncoder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   no existe o no es un directorio legible

Archivo `server.xml` de Tomcat 7.0

```
    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

  <Context docBase="C:\work\SpringMVCSignupLoginPasswordEncoder\target\SpringMVCSignupLoginPasswordEncoder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\" path="/SpringMVCSignupLoginPasswordEncoder" reloadable="true" /></Host>
```

En el tutorial dice que copie la URL donde se encuentra el proyecto, lo cua ya hice, si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería mucho.

> Herramientas:
>   -Java 8
>   -Spring 4 MVC
>   -Tomcat 7.0
>   -MySql

Comment: Te fijaste si existe el directorio que dice el error?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui proponen una solución al mismo problema.

https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/1690323